# VBA Global variables. Compile error: Only comments may appear after End Sub, End Function, or End Property

Tags: vba

I've declared my global variables throughout the same module and couldn't figure out why I get the Compile error: Only comments may appear after End Sub, End Function, or End Property.

Comment: They must be added on top of the module (in the declarations area). If a standard module and declared as `Public` they can be accessed from the whole project without mentioning the module name. If `Private` they can be accessed only from the respective module. If `Public`, but in a form, sheet code module or `ThisWorkbook` code module, they can be accessed only using the module name (as prefix) followed by a dot and variable name (`Sheet1.MyVariable`)... Intellisense will show it on the suggestions list (only if it is `Public`).

Comment: Check my answer to this question @braX, there's no precise detail about what FaneDuru and I myself answered to this question, i.e. the top place of declaration of the variables. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You must declare the variables at the top of the module. The variables will be available for all the Sub procedures in the same module.